# JQuery toggle and scroll

Tags: php, jquery, document-ready

Using this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpressley1/fccCJ/59/) I´m able to toggle and scroll to content, working in a html document.

After moving it to php (wordpress) the content remain hidden. The scroll functionality works.

I´m linking the script at the beggining of the text editor; I have tried so far to wrap the function in different ways (all of them works in html tests) but none of them displays the hidden content in WP:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...



(function( $ ) {
"use strict"; $(function() {...

$(document).ready(function(){ ...
```

I´ve followed different instructions to enqueue the script in the right way for WP with no lucky at all.

Any clue why the function to show the hidden content is not working?

Comment: Did you try just following the wordpress codex, and replacing all that crap with just `jQuery(function($) { .... });`

Comment: I think Toggle was deprecated in jQuery 1.8.0, your jsfiddle shows you are using 1.9.1

Comment: Using jQuery(function($) { .... }); to wrap same result: content hidden, scroll works but the function to show it still does not work... "I think Toggle was deprecated in jQuery 1.8.0, your jsfiddle shows you are using 1.9.1 " So .... ¿?

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. Daniel You were right, It seems toggle was removed in 1.9.1.